# Displaying un-Subtracted tables in SQL

Tags: java, sql, database

I have 2 tables which provides list of all rooms and booked rooms. Can I Subtract the Room_Count with Room_Used?

```
Select type,count(room_number)as Room_Count from room group by type
```

Type | Room Count

A1   | 10

A2   | 10

```
Select type,count(room_number)as Booked_Count from room_used group by type
```

Type  | Booked_Count

A1    | 5

So I tried this Query

```
select a.type,count(a.room_count)-count(b.room_booked)as room_avail from room a,room_used b where a.room=b.room_used
```

Type  | Room_avail

A1    | 5

It seems fine at start,but how to display the un-substracted ones,like this?

Type   | Room_avail

A1     | 5

A2      | 10

Comment: Please tag your database

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.type,count(a.room_count)-count(ISNULL(b.room_booked,0)) as Room_Count 
FROM   room a LEFT JOIN room_used b on a.room = b.room_used
```

[What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)